# sum of sequences which converge in distribution

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, weak-convergence

Assume that we have two sequences $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$, taking values in some Hilbert space, defined on the same probability space and assume that
$$
X_{n}\overset{d}{\to} X'
$$
and
$$
Y_{n}\overset{d}{\to} Y'
$$

**Statement:** $X_{n} + Y_{n} = O_{p}(1)$.

**Attempt:** Since both $X_{n}$ and $Y_{n}$ converge in distribution, then $X_{n} = O_{p}(1)$ and $Y_{n} = O_{p}(1)$. Then, the statement follows from the fact that
$$
O_{p}(n^{a}) + O_{p}(n^{b}) = O_{p}(n^{\max(a,b)}).
$$

Therefore, the conclusion is that if two sequences are defined on the same probability space and they converge in distribution, then their sum is stochastically bounded, even though the sum does not necessarily have a limit.

Is my conjecture correct?

Comment: Could you state what you mean by the notation $O_p(m)$?

Comment: I mean Big $O$ in probability. Check, for example, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_in_probability_notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P\|X_n+Y_n\|>2M)\leq P(\|X_n\|>M)+P(\|Y_n\|>M)$ and we can choose $M$ such that each of the two terms is   less that $\epsilon /2$.

Comment: which means that you agree with my proof. Yes?

Comment: I think $$
O_{p}(n^{a}) + O_{p}(n^{b}) = O_{p}(n^{\max(a,b)}).
$$ needs a  justification and that is what I did by explictly wrting an inequality.  @LrM